# How can I get the subset from an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, integer, subset, hashset

I'm working on a problem that asks me to "Write a method that returns all of the subsets of the set formed by the integers 1 to N where N is passed to the method." If I pass N = 3 to the method my output should look like `[[0], [1], [2], [3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]`. My current output is `[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3]].` Is there a way for me to print out the desired range like doing Arrays.copyOfRange() for the ArrayList? or is there another way of getting the subset with my desired output?;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class HW3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(powerset(3));
    }

    public static ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>> powerset(int N) {
        ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>> arrayList = new ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>>();
        HashSet<Integer> arrayListNew = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++)
            arrayListNew.add(i);

        for (int i = 0; i < (int) Math.pow(2, N); i++)
            arrayList.add(arrayListNew);

        return arrayList;
    }
}
```

Comment: An `ArrayList` is not an array, so `Arrays.copyOfRange()` can't be used with a `ArrayList`. Always use the abstract type with a method definition, ie `public static List<Set<Integer>> powerset(int N) {` and variables, ie `List<Set<Integer>> arrayList = new ArrayList<Set<>>();`

Comment: If N is 3,why `0` appear in your exepcted output?

Comment: probably representing the empty set

Comment: @Bohemian I understand that. The reason I mentioned it was to determine if there was a way to copy a range in the ArrayList and return it to get my desired output otherwise I'm not sure how I would get the subset.

Comment: @lucumt I have checked your answer however for this problem I need to use the method public static ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>> powerset(int N). I have seen examples that use a similar style to yours but they wouldn't work for me in my case.

Comment: @EzequielSolerPerez `List<List<Integer>> resultList = new ArrayList<>();` is similar to your output parameter,you just need to modify it

Comment: To answer your question literally, you can use [`subList(fromIndex, toIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#subList(int,int)) to get a *view* of a list’s range. To copy it into a new list, you can use, e.g. `new ArrayList<>(sourceList.subList(fromIndex, toIndex))`. But if you’re not going to modify the lists, you might not need to copy the range at all. It’s not clear to me why you think you need a `copyOfRange` like operation anyway.

Answer (score 0):

"Is there a way for me to print out the desired range like doing Arrays.copyOfRange() for the ArrayList?"

yes, use sublist() read more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList-int-int-)

However, you don't need that for your question. The algorithm you are looking for should look sth like this

```
//1st for loop iterate through all the possible sizes for the hash set
for(){
   //2nd for loop generate all possible combinations given the size
   for(){
   }
}
//might need to add the [0] urself at the end
```

Answer (score 0):

The more suitable way to do this is [**Backtracking**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking)

```
public class BacktrackTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        powerset(3);
    }

    public static void powerset(int num) {
        if (num >= 10 || num < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        int[] chs = new int[num];
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
            chs[i - 1] = i;
        }
        List<List<Integer>> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
        backtrack(0, chs, new ArrayList<>(), resultList);
        Collections.sort(resultList, (a, b) -> {
           int len1 = a.size();
           int len2 = b.size();
           return len1 - len2;
        });
        System.out.println(resultList);
    }

    public static void backtrack(int index, int[] chs, List<Integer> tempList, List<List<Integer>> resultList) {
        for (int i = index; i < chs.length; i++) {
            tempList.add(chs[i]);
            resultList.add(new ArrayList<>(tempList));
            backtrack(i + 1, chs, tempList, resultList);
            tempList.remove(tempList.size() - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

[**Java Fiddle Demo**](https://onecompiler.com/java/3yfuyesr5)

Output result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
public class HW3 {
static void printSubsets(int set[]) {
    int n = set.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < (1 << n); i++) {
        System.out.print("{ ");
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            if ((i & (1 << j)) > 0)
                System.out.print(set[j] + " ");

        System.out.println("}");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 3;
    int[] set = new int[n+1];
    for(int i = 0; i<=n; i++){
        set[i]=i;
    }
    printSubsets(set);
}}
```

The total number of subsets of any given set is equal to 2^ (no. of elements in the set). If we carefully notice it is nothing but binary numbers from 0 to 7 which can be shown as below:

> 000
> 001
> 010
> 011
> 100
> 101
> 110
> 111

Starting from right, 1 at ith position shows that the ith element of the set is present as 0 shows that the element is absent. Therefore, what we have to do is just generate the binary numbers from 0 to 2^n – 1, where n is the length of the set or the numbers of elements in the set.

**Time complexity:** O(n * (2^n)) as the outer loop runs for O(2^n) and the inner loop runs for O(n).

Comment: You should document the limitations of this approach. Using `int` you can only handle up to 32 elements; the way you implemented it, it only works with at most 30 elements. And don’t use the legacy declaration syntax `int set[]`, use `int[] set`